# How to invoke superclass' method in a Clojure gen-class method?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a class that extends input stream Clojure via `gen-class`. If I want to invoke the parent class' method, how do I do that?

Comment: This is an old question, but sometimes it gets attention. FWIW, as I've used Clojure over the years, I've found that if I think I need the power of gen-class to get something like this done, it's easier just to write a little bit of Java.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `(doc gen-class)`<sup>1</sup>:

```
:exposes-methods {super-method-name exposed-name, ...}

It is sometimes necessary to call the superclass' implementation of an
overridden method.  Those methods may be exposed and referred in 
the new method implementation by a local name.
```

So, in order to be able to call the parent's `fooBar` method, you'd say

```
(ns my.custom.Foo
  (:gen-class
    ; ...
    :exposes-methods {fooBar parentFooBar}
    ; ...
    ))
```

Then to implement `fooBar`:

```
(defn -fooBar [this]
  (combine-appropriately (.parentFooBar this)
                         other-stuff))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In addition to the `:gen-class` facility provided by `ns` forms, there is a `gen-class` macro.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional information in the edit. The addition of the the . in the invocation is an important detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your actual question, but I have a little library to let you pretend InputStream is an interface instead of a class (so that you don't need gen-class at all). Check out [`io.core.InputStream`](https://github.com/flatland/io/blob/develop/src/java/io/core/InputStream.java), which lets you reify [`io.core.InputStreamable`](https://github.com/flatland/io/blob/develop/src/java/io/core/InputStreamable.java) and get out a customized InputStream. Whatever instance fields you need can just be locals closed over by the `reify`.

Comment: Interesting idea. I had thought about something like that, but ultimately want an input stream in case I want to hand these back to Java.

Comment: The whole point is that you do get an input stream. You create an InputStreamable describing your logic, and give that to InputStream, an AOTed Java class. Eg, `(InputStream. (reify InputStreamable (read ...) (skip ...)))`.

Comment: @Bill Forgot to @ you in the previous comment. I think that means you didn't get notified; apologies if you're now getting a second notification.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. That's what I get for responding before my morning coffee. BTW, I get notifications on comment responses w/o an at sign.