# How to call super class when extending a Java class using genclass in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I want to call a method in the super class from Clojure. I am extending a Java class using `:gen-class`.

```
(ns subclass.core
    (:gen-class
     :extends Baseclass))

(defn greet [] 
    "Hello from core")  ; how to call super.greet()?

(defn -main [& args]
    (greet))
```

Java Baseclass

```
public class Baseclass {
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello from Baseclass";
    }
}
```

**Edit**: as the linked example I tried

```
 (ns subclass.core
    (:gen-class
     :extends Baseclass
     :exposes-methods {greet pgreet})
    (:import Baseclass))

(defn greet []
    (.pgreet (Baseclass.)))

(defn -main [& args])
```

But when I call (greet) I am getting the error

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: pgreet for class Baseclass  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

Is this the right way to call the super class method?

**Update**: Got it. We create a different method which will intern call the base class method. 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/API_Examples/Java_Interaction#genclass
NB: that's not what the linked answer says.

Comment: Your code doesn't follow the answer in the duplicate.  You use `(.pgreet (BaseClass .))` instead of (.pgreet this)`.  There's a *huge* difference.

Comment: What is `this` arg? Isn't it the object of the class `Baseclass`? If not, `(defn greet [this] (.pgreet this))` how do I invoke `greet`? What do I pass for `this` arg?

Comment: No, if you followed the answer given in the other question, `this` would be an object of a *subclass* of the class `BaseClass`.  The `BaseClass` has no `pgreet` method -- it's the `gen-class`ed on that has a `pgreet` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke superclass' method in a Clojure gen-class method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060127/how-to-invoke-superclass-method-in-a-clojure-gen-class-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060127/how-to-invoke-superclass-method-in-a-clojure-gen-class-method) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9060367/440294).

Your example fails because your `greet` function tries to call the `pgreet` method on an instance of `BaseClass`.  You need to create an instance of the `gen-class`ed class.

For example, something like this:

```
(ns subclass.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends Baseclass
   :exposes-methods {greet pgreet})
  (:import Baseclass))

;; You need to define a function for the overridden method
(defn greet- [this]
  (. this (pgreet)))

(defn greet []
  ;; You need to use the *gen-class*ed class, not BaseClass
  (. (new subclass.core) (greet))))
```

Comment: I am getting ClassNotFoundException: subclass.core.

Comment: Did you [compile](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/compile) the `subclass.core` namespace?  You'll probably want to add an `:aot` entry to your `project.clj` to make this easier.

Comment: I added `:aot [subclass.core]` and now `lein repl` is not able to find `Baseclass`. I have `:java-source-paths ["src/java"]`. It's giving `ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Baseclass`. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: From another post, it was because of the naked class. Putting the java files in a package works fine.